# Which type of data is better to keep 'decimal' in MySQL?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, decimal

I must to save decimal values (with high accuracy) in MySQL Data Base. But in MySQL there are two types: decimal and numeric (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html ) and they require two number (first, second) and I don't know which those numbers is equal to C# type decimal in accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, `DECIMAL` and `NUMERIC` are the same. You can use any of these types to store exact numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

From the link you type:

> The DECIMAL and NUMERIC types store exact numeric data values. These
>   types are used when it is important to preserve exact precision, for
>   example with monetary data. In MySQL, NUMERIC is implemented as
>   DECIMAL, so the following remarks about DECIMAL apply equally to
>   NUMERIC.

I think they are exactly the same in most RDBMS. But maybe some day they will become different (I doubt that):

> The difference between DECIMAL(s,p) and NUMERIC(s,p) is subtle in the 
>   SQL-92 Standard -- DECIMAL(s,p) must be exactly as precise as 
>   declared, while NUMERIC(s,p) must be at least as precise as declared.